# Results of a survival analysis change when converting the data to counting process format

Tags: regression, survival, regression-coefficients, cox-model

Consider the following simple example:

```r
library( survival )
data( veteran )

 coef( coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno, 
           data = veteran) )
         trt        prior        karno 
 0.180197194 -0.005550919 -0.033771018
```

Note that we have *neither* time-dependent covariates, *nor* time-varying coefficients, so the results should be the same if we change to counting process format, no matter where we cut the times.

That's true if we cut at event times:

```r
veteran2 <- survSplit( Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno,
                       data = veteran, cut = unique( 
                              veteran$time ) )

 coef( coxph(Surv(tstart,time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno, 
                  data = veteran2 ) )
         trt        prior        karno 
 0.180197194 -0.005550919 -0.033771018
```

But quite interestingly not true, if we cut at every day:

```r
veteran3 <- survSplit( Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno,
                       data = veteran, cut = 1:max(veteran$time) )

 coef( coxph(Surv(tstart,time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno, 
                  data = veteran3 ) )
         trt        prior        karno 
 0.180197215 -0.005550913 -0.033771016
```

The difference is not large, but definitely more than just a rounding error, or something like that.

What's going on? How can the results get wrong, especially by including *more* cutpoints?